# How to only checkmarking the selected item?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

as a beginner i know that code is used from **[FMX.ListViewCheckList Sample](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.ListViewCheckList_Sample)** to put the checkmark accessory on the selected item:

```
  if AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible then
   begin
     AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := False;
     FChecked.Remove(AItem.Index);
   end
   else
   begin
     AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := True;
     FChecked.Add(AItem.Index)
   end;
```

But i want one selected item checmarked at a time so that If i check another item, the previous is unchecked.
the code i did doesn't work:

```
procedure TMainForm.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if Assigned(ListView1.Selected) and (AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible) then
  begin
    AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := False;
    FChecked.Add(AItem.Index);
  end else
  begin
    AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := True;
    FChecked.Remove(AItem.Index);
  end;
end;
```

So cant you point me to the right direction How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply save the checked item when it's checked, and uncheck it when another is checked.

```
CheckedItem:TListViewItem;  //Declared as a private field in your form.

procedure TMainForm.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
if AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible then begin
     AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := False;
     FChecked.Remove(AItem.Index);
     CheckedItem:=nil;
   end
   else begin
     if Assigned(CheckedItem) then begin   //If you've already checked an item, uncheck that one.
       CheckedItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := False;
       FChecked.Remove(CheckedItem.Index);
     end;
     AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := True;
     FChecked.Add(AItem.Index);
     CheckedItem:=AItem;  //Save this one.
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, It works! i understand i was in wrong logic. Thanks!

Comment: @philip-j-rayment; i've another issue, accessory property resets to its default value. How to Save status of the checked state when When listview is resized?

Comment: Solve it: in `procedure TMainForm.ListView1UpdateObjects` add `if Assigned(CheckedItem)` condition and inside it put `FChecked.Contains(FCurrentCurrency.Index)`.

Answer (score 0):

And in the Update event:

```
procedure TMainForm.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  // Restore checked state when device is rotated.
  // When listview is resized because of rotation, accessory properties will be reset to default values
   if Assigned(CheckedItem) then  //If already checked an item, uncheck that one.
    begin
      CheckedItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := False; // or True, it depends
      FChecked.Contains(CheckedItem.Index);
    end;

end;
```